# Angular 6: Call function on mat-cell

Tags: typescript

I try to use the Angular Material Table which works well. My only problem is that I cant call a function which generates a value for a cell.

This is the part of my code:

```html
 <table mat-table [dataSource]="actuals"   *ngIf="actuals?.length > 0">

          <!-- Column Delivery Date -->
          <ng-container matColumnDef="deliveryDate" cdkColumnDef="deliveryDate">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef >Datum</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.deliveryDate}} </td>
          </ng-container>
          
          <!-- Add header and rows -->
          <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="['deliveryDate']"></tr>
          <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: ['deliveryDate']"></tr>
</table>
```

The dataSource "actuals" is an Array of "Actual" Objects which looks like this:

```html
import {Time} from "@angular/common";

export class Actual {
  id: number;
  coworkerName: string;
  taskCodeId: string;
  deliveryDate: Date;
  startTime: Time;
  endTime: Time;
  hours: number;
  comment: string;
  uploadType: string;
  modUser: string;
  modDate: Date;
  modComment: string;
  modStatus: string;

  constructor(id: number, coworkerName: string, taskCodeId: string, deliveryDate: Date, startTime: Time, endTime: Time, hours: number, comment: string, uploadType: string, modUser: string, modDate: Date, modComment: string, modStatus: string) {
    this.id = id;
    this.coworkerName = coworkerName;
    this.taskCodeId = taskCodeId;
    this.deliveryDate = deliveryDate;
    this.startTime = startTime;
    this.endTime = endTime;
    this.hours = hours;
    this.comment = comment;
    this.uploadType = uploadType;
    this.modUser = modUser;
    this.modDate = modDate;
    this.modComment = modComment;
    this.modStatus = modStatus;
  }
}
```

So everything works fine. But now i don't want to call

```html
{{element.deliveryDate}}
```

as value - instead I want to call a function. For example

```html
{{ element.deliveryDate.getDate() }}
<!-- Or -->
{{ doSomething(element) }}
```

but when I do that i get always an errormessage like

```
>ERROR TypeError: _v.context.$implicit.deliveryDate.getDate is not a function
>>    at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (ActualsComponent.html:50)
>>    at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.js:22503)
>>    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:21878)
>>    at callViewAction (core.js:22114)
>>    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:22077)
>>    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:21874)
>>    at callViewAction (core.js:22114)>
>>    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:22056)
>>    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:21879)
>>    at callViewAction (core.js:22114)
```

So what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Your DataSource probably doesn't contain an array of Actual objects, but an array of POJOs that were obtained by deserializing JSON, probably from an HTTP call. So deliveryDate exists as a property, but is not of type Date. Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem, as a stackblitz. See https://stackblitz.com/angular/jnpmaajmjod?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.html: it works fine if the deliveryDate is actually a Date. See https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-knjrww?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.ts: it produces your exact error if it's actually a string, and not a Date.

Answer (score 2):

Your error message said

> deliveryDate.getDate is not a function

thus, it does not exist in your typesrcipt class.

To call a function in `mat-cell` , do as below , it will call a function named doSomething(deliveryDate: Date) in typescript class.

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{doSomething(element.deliveryDate)}} </td>
```

Then create a function below in your typescript class

```
  doSomething(deliveryDate: Date) {
  return "Delivery date is  " + deliveryDate;
  }
```

So, in each row of your table, the output will be shown like

> Delivery date is (date from dataSource)

Comment: Can you add some explanation for your code? Its hard to tell what its doing

Comment: Nani, this is just what I was looking for. I have a curious bug though. This works when I load the table initially inside a nested <app-component>, but when I click through one of the items to a detail view and then nav back, the following Type error is given: dataItem_r778.getVesselLength is not a function. Why would it work initially, but then fail on a nav back?

Comment: I found the issue. I was using the @CacheableClass decorator on the TS model which was breaking the function. Sad to lose that feature but I think my function in the table row is more important.